# on Delete casacade MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I got an ID for one of my tables and I want to make it "on delete cascade" but it wont let me change the properties of the ID value to "on delete cascade" because it is a foreign key, is there any way to change this without having to drop my table and create it again?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the relationship, change the field, and then establish the relationship again? That way the field loses its status as a foreign key, and then you can change its properties, I think. (please let mi know if it works).

Comment: Try something from here 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571581/how-to-add-on-delete-cascade-in-alter-table-statement 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506994/sql-alter-table-on-delete-cascade