# Mysql: delete rows in two tables with foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with data.
I want to delete rows in both tables.
But I have foreign keys between them.
How can I do this?

```
 departure
     id    departure_date
      1        2016-09-29
      2        2016-09-30

 departure_time
     id    departure_id (fk)
      1         1
      2         2
```

the best thing would be to have a query that gets all rows to be deleted, and deletes rows in both tables at the same time. 
Is there a way to do this without removing constraints/FK?

In this example, say I would like to delete all departures from date 2016-09-30

(delete departure: id 2 and departure_time: id: 2)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please try this, hope it will help.

```
DELETE FROM departure, departure_time
USING departure
INNER JOIN departure_time
WHERE departure_date = '2016-09-30'
      AND departure_time.id = departure.id
```

Or

```
DELETE FROM departure, departure_time
USING departure
INNER JOIN departure_time
WHERE departure_date = '2016-09-30'
      AND departure_time.departure_id = departure.id
```

Or you can use `ON DELETE CASCADE` that will do work automatically for you .

Comment: Hi Mumesh , am I wrong or the two queries you have written are identical? Thank you for confirming o highlight the difference.

Comment: He is using two different columns `id` and `departure_id`, although only `departure_id` would be the correct one.

Comment: Easy way to do this through PHPMYADMIN, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32244787/1408137.  The answer is for Oracle, but applicable to MySQL.

Answer (score 8):

In MySQL, you can also delete from multiple tables in one statement:

```
delete d, dt
    from departure d join
         departure_time dt
         on d.id = dt.departure_id
    where departure_date = '2016-09-30';
```

Another solution is to declare the foreign key relationship as `on delete cascade`.  Then when you delete the row in the original table, the database will delete the related records in the second table.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this did not work.
Had to change dt.id to dt.departure_id
Then it got an error
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`osl`.`departure_time`, CONSTRAINT `departure_time_departure_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`departure_id`) REFERENCES `departure` (`id`))

Answer (score 1):

The multiple row delete failed for me because there were multiple rows in the second table referencing the first table. I was also unable to update the schema in order to add a foreign key constraint (as suggested in other answers).

Using IN like so worked:

```
DELETE FROM departure_time
WHERE departure_id IN (
        SELECT departure_id
        FROM departure
        WHERE departure_date = '2016-09-30'
    );
DELETE from departure
WHERE departure_date = '2016-09-30'
```