# How can i delete data from database with foreign key constraint in mysql using php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have three Tables in database.

table 1

**projects**

```
PK ProjectID
```

table 2

**students**

```
PK RegNo
FK ProjectID
```

table 3

**progress**

```
FK RegNo
```

Now the thing I want to perform a delete operation when I delete the record from a project it should be deleted from students, as students primary key is also present as foreign key progress table, so it should also delete RegNo from progress table. How I can achieve this as the best possible way. Thanks in advance.

```
$query = "DELETE students, progress from students inner join progress on progress.RegNo=students.RegNo where students.ProjectID='$id';DELETE FROM projects where projects.ProjectID='$id'";

//$conn->exec($query);
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

it gives foreign key constraint violation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql: delete rows in two tables with foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768995/mysql-delete-rows-in-two-tables-with-foreign-keys)

Comment: which foreign key is being violated?

Comment: I am having this error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`projectmgmt_osman`.`progress`, CONSTRAINT `progress_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`RegNo`) REFERENCES `students` (`RegNo`))' in C:\xampp\htdocs\projectmanager\adminhome.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be easier to split deletes into separate queries.

```
 DELETE FROM `progress` 
        WHERE `RegNo` IN(
          SELECT `RegNo` FROM `students` WHERE ProjectID = '$id'
        ); 

 DELETE FROM `student` WHERE `ProjectID` = '$id';
 DELETE FROM `projects` WHERE `ProjectID` = '$id';
```

Comment: Now it doesn't give an violation but data is still there. Not deleted