# Query to delete primary & foreign key in same time

Tags: mysql, sql, phpquery

Hello everybody i have two tables which are this structure

invoice table :

```
invoice_id
customer_name
order_date
```

invoice_infos :

```
id
invoice_id
production_name
product_prix
qtt
```

Now I wanna make a query which delete in same time a row which are the same invoice_no in two tables

Comment: invoice_no  column not present in both the table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql: delete rows in two tables with foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39768995/mysql-delete-rows-in-two-tables-with-foreign-keys)

Answer (score 2):

if two tables are related and you are considering to delete record(s) from `invoice_infos` table whenever a record deleted from `invoice` table, you need `FOREIGN KEY` with `CASCADE DELETE`

```
alter table invoice_infos
add constraint invoice_fkey
foreign key (invoice_id)
references invoice(invoice_id)
on delete cascade;
```

after that whenever you issue

```
DELETE FROM invoice WHERE invoice_id = 5;
```

the related values on invoice_infos will also get deleted

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [Multiple-Table `DELETE` Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html) :

```
DELETE invoice, invoice_infos
FROM invoice
INNER JOIN invoice_infos ON invoice.invoice_id = invoice_infos.invoice_id
WHERE invoice.invoice_id = ?;
```

You can replace the `?` with the id of the invoice that you want to get rid of.