# Is it possible to add a cascading delete to an existing relationship using FluentMigrator

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator

Is it possible to add a cascading delete to an existing relationship using FluentMigrator. So could I replace the following two lines with a one-liner?

```
Delete.ForeignKey("FK_Attachments_Items").OnTable("Attachments");
Create.ForeignKey("FK_Attachments_Items").FromTable("Attachments").ForeignColumn("ItemId").ToTable("Items").PrimaryColumn("Id").OnDeleteOrUpdate(System.Data.Rule.Cascade);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to add a cascading delete rule to an existing relation because SQL doesn't support it. Which is why Fluent Migrator doesn't offer such functionality. It could offer a wrapper to recreate a foreign key with the cascading delete rule, but it doesn't. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571581/how-to-add-on-delete-cascade-in-alter-table-statement) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356484/how-to-add-on-delete-cascade-constraints) stackoverflow post for more information.